# specify Database to DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework Code First and am creating a DbContext using a connection string. If the connection string does not specify an Initial Catalog, is there some way I can configure the DbContext to use a specific database on the server (without setting the Initial Catalog on the connection string)

I looked at the configuration options available off of modelBuilder in the OnModelCreating event in my derived DbContext class, but nothing jumped out at me.  Obviously, if I set the initial catalog on the connection string things work as I want them to.

Comment: Whats the problem specifying the Initial Catalog?
You need it in order to point to the correct DB

Comment: I want to hard code the database name into the DbContext class itself.  That way, if someone messes with the connection string and either removes the initial catalog or changes it I would still be targeting the correct database via EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could choose the name of the DB like this:

```
public class MyDataContext : DbContext {
    public MyDataContext() : base("MyDatabaseName") 
    {
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(myConnectionString);
    }
}
```