# How to define database after the connection is established in MYSQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have MYSQL connection string ready and connection is established.

This one is connecting with the database

`Server={0}; Port={1}; database={2}; UID={3}; password={4}", Server, Port, Database, Username, Password`

And this one is connecting without database (I am currently using)

`"Server={0}; Port={1}; UID={2}; password={3}", Server, Port, Username, Password`

I use the second one and want to select or define the database after the connection is established. Is there any way? I have no idea how, this is for the first time I came into this problem.

Comment: [Entity Framework Code First maybe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16698871/581076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. use `ChangeDatabase()`

```
string conn = ($"Server={0}; Port={1}; UID={2}; password={3}", Server, Port, Username, Password);

MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn);
con.Open();
con.ChangeDatabase("Your db");
```

Comment: YESSS! I should have thought of playing with connection variable. Thanks btw